# Control Chrome Extensions C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to control an installed extensions on chrome browser? For example - I want to switch a location of VPN I use without manually clicking on the extension and selecting location.

I just can't find anyting that makes me able to interact with EXTEMSIONS themselves, not the website/etc.

Comment: Try specialized browser automation tools like ChromeDriver and similar that use remote-debugging protocol.

Comment: With use of the Selenium and interface of the extension(Extension ID/POPUP.HTML) + Dev mode - I can extract the code of the popup and instruct selenium to guide on it so It makes me able to control the Extension(not completely tho).